# Does elm have haskell like lens or something similar?

Tags: elm

In haskell I use the lens library. Is there something similar in elm?
If I have this elm data structure, how could I add 3 to `test.a.b`.

```
test = {
  a = {
    b = 5
  }
 }
```

In haskell I would write: `test & a.b ~% (+3)`.
In haskell I can write `makeLenses ''RecordName` and automatically generate lenses, does elm have that?

Comment: Googling for "elm lens" yields [elm-monocle](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/arturopala/elm-monocle/1.2.0/Monocle-Lens) (last updated [four months ago](https://github.com/arturopala/elm-monocle)) and [focus](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/focus/2.0.1/Focus) (last updated [one month ago](https://github.com/evancz/focus)).

Comment: @Rhymoid It looks like you have to manually declare the lens

Comment: As far as I can see, yes, you'd have to explicitly define them. While `lens` can generate the Haskell code for you through Template Haskell, Elm does not have such metaprogramming capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of. It has the [Focus](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/focus/2.0.1/) library. It would allow you to say something like:

```
Focus.update (a => b) ((+) 3) test
```

...to add three to `test.a.b`. It has two drawbacks that spring to mind. The first is that you have to create your lenses by hand. This isn't a big deal. For your `test` record above, to create a lens (or focus) by hand, you first need a getter function, which is trivial:

```
.a
```

And then a map function, which can apply a function to `a` given `test`:

```
\f test = { test | a = f test.a }
```

Now you can combine those two to make a focus:

```
a =
    Focus.create
        .a
        (\f test = { test | a = f test.a })
```

Do the same for `b`:

```
b =
    Focus.create
        .b
        (\f a = { a | b = f a.b })
```

And now you can combine these two foci with `(a => b)` and that lets you make the `Focus.update` call shown above. So there's a bit of boilerplate, but it's no great hardship, and you can do nested gets/sets/updates to your heart's content.

The bigger limitation is, you can't do prisms. So if there's a `Maybe` involved in your path, you're blocked. Back to doing the nested update the long-long-longhand way.

<s>Why are there no prisms? Because they need higher kinded types, and Elm doesn't have those. (Yet?)</s>

So the answer's yes & no. You can have something Lens-like, but don't expect the full power of Haskell lenses.

Update: Looks like I was wrong on my last point - [Monacle](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/arturopala/elm-monocle/1.2.0/Monocle-Prism) provides Prisms. I didn't think it was possible. I stand corrected!

Comment: Monocle appears to have focuses.

Comment: Thanks @2426021684! I've updated my answer, and now I need to go an learn how it's possible. :-D